# Serverless example not working with serverless-localstack plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, localstack

I am running an example from the official [serverless GitHub](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-python-rest-api-with-dynamodb) page and it works well out of the box when I deploy directly on my AWS account.

Now when I try to activate the [serverless-localstack](https://github.com/localstack/serverless-localstack) plugin by changing `serverless.yml` accordingly:

```
service: serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

custom:
  localstack:
    stages:
    - local
    - dev
    endpoints:
      S3: http://localhost:4572
      DynamoDB: http://localhost:4570
      CloudFormation: http://localhost:4581
      Elasticsearch: http://localhost:4571
      ES: http://localhost:4578
      SNS: http://localhost:4575
      SQS: http://localhost:4576
      Lambda: http://localhost:4574
      Kinesis: http://localhost:4568

plugins:
  - serverless-localstack

functions:
  create:
    handler: todos/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: todos/list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: todos/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    handler: todos/update.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true

  delete:
    handler: todos/delete.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    TodosDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

I get the following error on the `localstack` side (running in docker):

```
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 09:48:15,260:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 09:48:15] "GET /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-ServerlessDeploymentBucket-5YYKLD61WXMT?location HTTP/1.1" 404 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:15:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_listener: Error response from CloudFormation (400) POST /: b'<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudformation.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-15/">\n  <Error>\n    <Type>Sender</Type>\n    <Code>ValidationError</Code>\n    <Message>Stack with id serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local does not exist</Message>\n  </Error>\n  <RequestId>cf4c737e-5ae2-11e4-a7c9-ad44eEXAMPLE</RequestId>\n</ErrorResponse>'
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:15:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Currently updating stack resource serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local/ServerlessDeploymentBucket: None
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:15:ERROR:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Unable to parse and create resource "ServerlessDeploymentBucket": 400 Bad Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
localstack_1  | <Error>
localstack_1  |     <Code>InvalidBucketName</Code>
localstack_1  |     <Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message>
localstack_1  |     
localstack_1  |     <RequestID>7a62c49f-347e-4fc4-9331-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestID>
localstack_1  | </Error> Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_starter.py", line 173, in parse_and_create_resource
localstack_1  |     return _parse_and_create_resource(logical_id, resource_json, resources_map, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_starter.py", line 229, in _parse_and_create_resource
localstack_1  |     resource_json_arns_fixed, resources_map, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/parsing.py", line 306, in parse_and_create_resource
localstack_1  |     resource_name, resource_json, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/s3/models.py", line 701, in create_from_cloudformation_json
localstack_1  |     bucket = s3_backend.create_bucket(resource_name, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/s3/models.py", line 714, in create_bucket
localstack_1  |     raise InvalidBucketName()
localstack_1  | moto.s3.exceptions.InvalidBucketName: 400 Bad Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
localstack_1  | <Error>
localstack_1  |     <Code>InvalidBucketName</Code>
localstack_1  |     <Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message>
localstack_1  |     
localstack_1  |     <RequestID>7a62c49f-347e-4fc4-9331-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestID>
localstack_1  | </Error>
localstack_1  | 
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:15:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_listener: Error response from CloudFormation (400) POST /: b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error>\n    <Code>InvalidBucketName</Code>\n    <Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message>\n    \n    <RequestID>7a62c49f-347e-4fc4-9331-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestID>\n</Error>'
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04 09:48:34,571:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2019 09:48:34] "GET /serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local-ServerlessDeploymentBucket-C5ZNB3XCGTSA?location HTTP/1.1" 404 -
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:34:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_listener: Error response from CloudFormation (400) POST /: b'<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudformation.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-15/">\n  <Error>\n    <Type>Sender</Type>\n    <Code>ValidationError</Code>\n    <Message>Stack with id serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local does not exist</Message>\n  </Error>\n  <RequestId>cf4c737e-5ae2-11e4-a7c9-ad44eEXAMPLE</RequestId>\n</ErrorResponse>'
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:34:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Currently updating stack resource serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-local/ServerlessDeploymentBucket: None
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:34:ERROR:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Unable to parse and create resource "ServerlessDeploymentBucket": 400 Bad Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
localstack_1  | <Error>
localstack_1  |     <Code>InvalidBucketName</Code>
localstack_1  |     <Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message>
localstack_1  |     
localstack_1  |     <RequestID>7a62c49f-347e-4fc4-9331-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestID>
localstack_1  | </Error> Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_starter.py", line 173, in parse_and_create_resource
localstack_1  |     return _parse_and_create_resource(logical_id, resource_json, resources_map, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/cloudformation/cloudformation_starter.py", line 229, in _parse_and_create_resource
localstack_1  |     resource_json_arns_fixed, resources_map, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/parsing.py", line 306, in parse_and_create_resource
localstack_1  |     resource_name, resource_json, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/s3/models.py", line 701, in create_from_cloudformation_json
localstack_1  |     bucket = s3_backend.create_bucket(resource_name, region_name)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/s3/models.py", line 714, in create_bucket
localstack_1  |     raise InvalidBucketName()
localstack_1  | moto.s3.exceptions.InvalidBucketName: 400 Bad Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
localstack_1  | <Error>
localstack_1  |     <Code>InvalidBucketName</Code>
localstack_1  |     <Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message>
localstack_1  |     
localstack_1  |     <RequestID>7a62c49f-347e-4fc4-9331-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestID>
localstack_1  | </Error>
localstack_1  | 
localstack_1  | 2019-12-04T09:48:34:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_listener: Error response from CloudFormation (400) POST /: b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error>\n    <Code>InvalidBucketName</Code>\n    <Message>The specified bucket is not valid.</Message>\n    \n    <RequestID>7a62c49f-347e-4fc4-9331-6e8eEXAMPLE</RequestID>\n</Error>'
```

Is there a missing config in `serverless.yml` for the localstack plugin to work ?

The command I use for deploying is:

> SLS_DEBUG=3 serverless deploy --stage local --region us-east-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only tried localstack once and did not have success with local stack. I have googled for you and found an answer. see if its working.

```
provider:
  deploymentBucket:
    name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-deployment-bucket
```

reference: https://github.com/localstack/serverless-localstack/issues/30

Comment: Thank you, it improves the result, in that I get a single 404 error on the localstack docker side of things. I will keep digging.

Comment: After I manually created the bucket your answer un-blocked me, so happily accepting it. I will create a new post for my new blocking point.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once and as suggested by @arun-k I added `deploymentBucket`. It worked well although I faced other issues, so I pulled a tagged image of `LocalStack` (i.e. `image: localstack/localstack:0.10.5`) instead of the stable release and I didn't specify `deploymentBucket` again and it also works.

Thought it might be useful for others.